# Disable hl-line-mode only for eshell and ansi-term

Tags: hooks, minor-mode, hl-line-mode

I have `global-hl-line-mode` setup in my init file:

```
(use-package hl-line
  :init (global-hl-line-mode 1))
```

Is it possible to disable it when I am in `eshell` and `ansi-term`?
I tried adding a hook like this:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (hl-line-mode -1))
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`global-hl-line-mode` sets variable `global-hl-line-mode` to `t`.  The global mode is separate from the non-global (`hl-line-mode`).

The following will disable it in the selected mode:

```lisp
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                    (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
                                                nil)))
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                    (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
                                                nil)))
```

The documentation indicates that setting it directly does not take effect, however when testing it it does remove the highlighting while in the `*Eshell*` buffer.

Comment: Works for ```eshell```, thank you. Now I need something for ```ansi-term```.

Comment: Try `term-mode-hook`.

Answer (score 3):

This works for `ansi-term` if you're using emacs 24.3+:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
                                        nil)))
```

Thanks to Jonathan and glucas.