# Can I override global-hl-line-mode in a buffer/window?

Tags: highlighting, buffer-local, global-mode, hl-line-mode

I have the following line turning hl-line-mode on globally in my init file:

```
(global-hl-line-mode)
```

Most of the time, that's how I like it. But sometimes I want to turn it off. I'd hoped that I could somehow override the global setting with a buffer-local one, by running `hl-line-mode` with a negative prefix argument. This does turn off the highlight for about a second, then it just comes back. I can, of course, disable `global-hl-line-mode` instead, but is there a way to do a buffer or window local override of this setting?

*Update* Kudos to @lawlist for the necessary mechanics. I bound this up in a little function and am quite happy with it.

```
(defun ivan/local-toggle-hl-line ()
  "Toggle line highlighting in current buffer"
  (interactive)
  (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
              (null global-hl-line-mode)))
```

Dedicating it to the same keybinding that iTerm2 uses for the same sort of thing <kbd>⌥⌘;</kbd>

Comment: How about?:  `(setq-local global-hl-line-mode nil)`  See -- **how to disable hl-line feature in specified mode**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990370/how-to-disable-hl-line-feature-in-specified-mode

Comment: Very closely related to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9747/115 ?

Comment: @lawlist That seems pretty counter-intuitive to me (a local global setting), but it works! Thank you