# Last line of eshell (in powerline theme) differ from the others

Tags: eshell

Here you see an Emacs 27 on Debian 11 with `eshell` using `powerline` as theme.

[image]

But the current/last line doesn't use the powerline theme correct. I can not figuring out what could this be.

This is the relevant part of my `init.el`.

```
(defun efs/configure-eshell ()
  ;; Save command history when commands are entered
  (add-hook 'eshell-pre-command-hook 'eshell-save-some-history)

  ;; Truncate buffer for performance
  (add-to-list 'eshell-output-filter-functions 'eshell-truncate-buffer)

  ;; Bind some useful keys for evil-mode
  (evil-define-key '(normal insert visual) eshell-mode-map (kbd "C-r") 'counsel-esh-history)
  (evil-define-key '(normal insert visual) eshell-mode-map (kbd "<home>") 'eshell-bol)
  (evil-normalize-keymaps)

  (setq eshell-history-size         10000
        eshell-buffer-maximum-lines 10000
        eshell-hist-ignoredups t
        eshell-scroll-to-bottom-on-input t))

(use-package eshell-git-prompt)

(use-package eshell
  :config
  (eshell-git-prompt-use-theme 'multiline)
  :hook (eshell-first-time-mode . efs/configure-eshell)
  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable hl-line-mode only for eshell and ansi-term](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9747/disable-hl-line-mode-only-for-eshell-and-ansi-term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `global-hl-line-mode` turned on, which changes the appearance of the line that point is on.

To turn it of (see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9748/12999):

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                    (setq-local global-hl-line-mode
                                                nil)))
```